# How to check for enum type

Tags: vb.net, enums

i have a function that checks what enum is in the parameters (i have more than 7 enum types) and returns an image based of it, but it doesn't work.

like this

```
       Enum TrophyType
            Gold
            Silver
            Bronze
        End Enum
        Enum Bla
             Bla1
             ....
        End Enum

       Public Shared Function InquireForImage(item As [Enum]) As BitmapImage
            Dim image As New BitmapImage
            Select Case item
                case TrophyType.Gold
                'return specific image
                case TrophyType.Silver
                 'return image
                case Bla.Bla1
                 'return image

            End Select
        End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `Function InquireForImage(item As TrophyType)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use different overloads:

```
   Public Shared Function InquireForImage(item As TrophyType) As BitmapImage
        Select Case item
            Case TrophyType.Gold
                Return LoadImage(...)
            Case TrophyType.Silver
                Return LoadImage(...)
            ...
        End Select
   End Function

   Public Shared Function InquireForImage(item As Bla) As BitmapImage
        Select Case item
            Case Bla.bla1
                Return LoadImage(...)
            ...
        End Select
   End Function
```

I would consider this cleaner than trying the determine the enum type in code. Here, the compiler is doing all the work for you. Make sure that you put all your image loading logic into a separate `LoadImage` method, so that you don't need to repeat yourself when you have multiple `InquireForImage` overloads.

---

Just for reference: If you *do* need a method that accepts multiple different Enum types, you can differentiate between them by using explicit type checks:

```
Public Function InquireForImage(ByVal item As [Enum]) As String
    If TypeOf item Is TrophyType Then
        Select Case DirectCast(item, TrophyType)
            Case TrophyType.Gold
                Return ...
            Case TrophyType.Silver
                Return ...
            ...
        End Select

    ElseIf TypeOf item Is Bla Then
        ...

    End If
End Function
```

In general, however, overloads should be preferred (see above).

Comment: i will go with the overload solution

Answer (score 1):

i managed to get many ways for it (thanks to @Heinzi)
one good way is using this

```
Public Shared Function InquireForImage(item As [Enum]) As BitmapImage
            Dim image As New BitmapImage
            Select Case item.GetType
                Case Is = GetType(TrophyType)
                    'that was my target as i wanted to use the wpf's [Resources(name)]
                    image = MainWindow.GetImageFromResources("tr_" & item.ToString())

            End Select

            Return image
        End Function
'Update -----------------------------------------------------
    Select Case item.GetType
                    Case Is = GetType(TrophyType)

                    Case Is = GetType(CamouFlages)
                        Select Case DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(CamouFlages), item.ToString), CamouFlages)
                            Case CamouFlages.Default_Camo
                                imagename = "Default_Camo"
                            ' etc ....
                        End Select

                    Case Else
                        Return Nothing

                End Select
```

Comment: Updated with how to use actual enums for checking and not just string

Answer (score 0):

Change the Function definition to the following and put all your Enum values in TrophyType.

```
Public Shared Function InquireForImage(item As TrophyType) As BitmapImage
```

Comment: i actually thought about this but this will be so hard to determine as i have like 17 different enums (Very large database)

Comment: You could either use method overloading, or add a custom attribute to each Enum value and then create an extension method to parse out a property value from the custom attribute. Here's a link with an example of what I mean: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/C-Enhance-Enums-using-Extension-Methods